# How to apply rolling line of best fit to a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I need to apply a line of best fit to every day in a dataframe.

What I have so far is:

```
def lobf(y):
    slope, intercept = stats.linregress(np.arange(len(y)), y)[:2]
    return((slope * np.arange(len(y))) + intercept)

rolling_lobf = df[["A"]].rolling(24, axis = 0).apply(lobf)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window.py", line 1850, in apply
    return super().apply(func, raw=raw, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window.py", line 1114, in apply
    return self._apply(f, func, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, center=False, raw=raw)
  File "C:\Users\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window.py", line 961, in _apply
    result = np.apply_along_axis(calc, self.axis, values)
  File "C:\Users\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\shape_base.py", line 380, in apply_along_axis
    res = asanyarray(func1d(inarr_view[ind0], *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window.py", line 956, in calc
    x, window, min_periods=self.min_periods, closed=self.closed
  File "C:\Users\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window.py", line 1111, in f
    kwargs,
  File "pandas\_libs\window.pyx", line 1649, in pandas._libs.window.roll_generic
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I really don't want to manually iterate over the dataframe and I'm pretty sure that df.rolling is the way to go; I just can't figure out why it's not working.

My dataframe looks like:

```
                            A
Time
2019-01-01 00:00:00+00:00   -9.706667
2019-01-01 01:00:00+00:00  -10.706667
2019-01-01 02:00:00+00:00   -6.886667
2019-01-01 03:00:00+00:00   -5.953333
2019-01-01 04:00:00+00:00   -3.953333
```

Ideally I would like to add a column which is the value of a line of best fit fitted to the past 24 hours.

Comment: What does your dataframe itself look like? What are the column/row labels, and what type of data is contained?

Comment: I think `rolling.apply` is supposed to return one scalar per row, while here your function return an array of 24 scalars, can you give data of your expected output

Answer (score 1):

I got it; thanks to Ben.T's comment.

What I've ended up doing is taking the average of the points on the line of best fit fitted to the past 24H:

```py
def lobf(y):
    slope, intercept = stats.linregress(np.arange(len(y)), y)[:2]
    return(((slope * np.arange(len(y))) + intercept).mean())

df["A"] = df[["A"]].rolling("24H").apply(lobf)
```